# Eclipse Plugin-Dev - how to mark package as internal

Tags: eclipse-plugin

**How can I mark a package as being internal?** (it should throw a warning when its classes are used)

There are plenty of examples of this in the Eclipse plug-ins (i.e. `org.eclipse.core.internal` )

By using only `import-package` / `export-package` directives instead of `require-bundle`, I could just omit the `export-package` directive in my plug-in, but the `internal` warning would be of use in the other case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `x-internal:=true` in the Export-Package directive:

```
Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core;x-internal:=true
```

There is also an `x-friends` directive to let to specify a list of bundles which can use the package.

More on this in the [Eclipse help for bundle manifest headers](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html)

When using the Manifest.mf editor you can specify this by switching to the 'Runtime' tab. Select the Exported Package you want to make internal and in the 'Package Visibility' section select 'hidden from all plugins except'. With no plugins in the except list you get x-internal, if you list plugins in the list you get x-friends.